# Is this graph and its spectrum understood?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, spectral-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

Consider the graph whose vertices are labelled by the binary representation of the integers from $0$ to $2^{d}-1$ for some $d \in \mathbb{N}$. So its a graph with $2^d$ vertices. An edge exists between two such vertices if the two binary strings differ in at most 2 bits. (for example for $d=2$ this is $K_4$. for $d=3$ this is the cube with all the face diagonals)

Is this graph and its spectrum known? 
If something is known about this graph's spectrum then cans someone kindly give the references?

Answer (score 3):

This graph is usually known as the halved $n$-cube. It is discussed on page 264 of Brouwer, Cohen and Neumaier "Distance-Regular Graphs". From there we see that the eigenvalues are
\[
  \theta_j = \frac12(n-2j)^2-\frac12n
\]
with respective multiplicities $\binom{n}{j}$ when $2j<n$; if $n=2d$ then $\theta_d$ has multiplicity $\frac12\binom{n}{d}$.

I outline one way to get the eigenvalues. Let $A_1$ denote the adjacency matrix of the $n$-cube and let $A_2$ be the adjacency matrix of the graph with the same vertices as the $n$-cube, but with two vertices adjacent if and only if they are at distance two in the $n$-cube. (This graph has two components, each of which is a halved $n$-cube.) Then we have
\[
    A_1^2 = nI+2A_2
\]
and therefore $A_2=\frac12(A_1^2-nI)$. The eigenvalues of the $n$-cube are the integers $n-2r$ for $r=0,\ldots,n$, so we get the eigenvalues of the halved $n$-cube s above.

Comment: Are you sure this is the same thing? The definition here doesn't seem to match, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HalvedCubeGraph.html

Comment: ^in the above link it says that the two vertices are adjacent iff the two vertices are at a distance $2$ in the original graph. But in the post the two vertices can be at distance one too.

Comment: They are two different descriptions of the same graph. See the wikipedia articles on the halved cubes.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil Can you point to a reference which derives this? The book you referred to doesn't seem to.

Comment: @guest: I've edited my post.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil Thanks! I was thinking of an alternative way - since the iegenvectors of this graph seem to be the same as that of the hypercube - can't we think of this graph as the Cayley graph over the same group but now the generating set is of all $d$ length strings which have all $0$s except for having a $1$ at atmost $2$ places.  Now look at the characters of this group, $\chi_r : \{ 0,1 \}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$ $x \rightarrow (-1)^{x.r}$.  Now shouldn't the eigenvalues of this graph be the vales $\sum_s \chi_r (s)$ (where the sum is taken over the generating set)?

Comment: (one such map for every $r \in \mathbb{Z}_2^d$)

Comment: @guest: That's correct, and is also a good way to do it. But it wasn't clear that I could appeal to information about the eigenvectors of the $n$-cube.